# Symmetries of a rectangle

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

I am currently bginner studying abstract algebra. And while studying groups and symmetries of rectangle, I found that there are only four symmetries of rectangle mentioned namely: identity, 180 degrees rotation, vertical reflection and horizontal reflection. But, why are not reflections along diagonals included?

EDIT: thanks for the comments. I just realized that along the diagonals, rectangle does not have symmetry.

Comment: In general, rectangles are not symmetric across their diagonals.  A square would be the exception.

Comment: http://s3.amazonaws.com/illustrativemathematics/images/000/001/611/max/rectanglereflection6_ec8250e8f6e17e477b48967eaa13e255.jpg?1350430301 You see that the resulting shape cannot be translated so that it coincides with the original

Comment: Thank you people, I just realized after reading your comments and seeing the image.

Comment: Note that a symmetry must map vertices to vertices, edges to edges, faces to faces, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reflections along diagonals are not symmetries of a general rectangle - they "exchange" (imperfectly except for a square) the long side and the short side.

To have a symmetry by reflection in a diagonal the adjacent sides have to be the same length.

Comment: yes, and the diagonals should intersect perpendicularly(in case of square and rhombus)